# Parse + CocoaPods + xcode7: framework not found Bolts

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, cocoapods, xcode7

I added in podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

add `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` and `OTHER_LDFLAGS - $(inherit)`

all frameworks integrated
[image]

and compiling project but an error:

> ld: framework not found Bolts
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Comment: ok, I added text error

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
Go to `Framework Search Paths` and check the order.
It should be- 1)Bolts  2)FB  3)Parse.

Comment: In my `Framework Search Paths` I set `$(inherited)` it's cocoapods recomendation. [screenshot](https://pp.vk.me/c627721/v627721607/17608/04aNE1k8fHY.jpg)